# Issues with using Expectation Maximization algorithm

Tags: maximum-likelihood, optimization, expected-value, convergence, expectation-maximization

I was using the EM algorithm to maximize a partially observed likelihood. However, I have certain doubts. Normally, the algorithm works fine. I could print the value of the log likelihood of the observed data that I am trying to minimize and the values keeps on going down and converge. However, at times, I could see that it goes down for a while and then starts increasing. What could be the reason for that? As far as the code is concerned, I am pretty sure it's fine. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Three possibilities that come to mind:

1. Numerical stability problems: due to the scale of the numbers you are dealing with, the floating point representation causes small inaccuracies that may become significant. This usually happens when combining numbers on very different scales.
2. Incorrect likelihood/gradient: you may have calculated the likelihood or gradient incorrectly.
3. Incorrect implementation of EM: have you implemented EM before? there may be some gap in understanding of the algorithm (no disrespect meant).

From your description it sounds like it is probably numerical issues.